# Automatic differentiation of integral

Tags: automatic-differentiation

I would like to compute the integral

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 F(x,y,\xi, \eta) \; d\xi \; d\eta
$$

or moving the derivative inside the integrals

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} F(x,y,\xi, \eta) \; d\xi \; d\eta
$$

where $F(x,y,\xi, \eta)$ is a complicated rational function, the derivative of which is certain to result in [expression swell](http://kfe.fjfi.cvut.cz/%7Eliska/ca/node53.html).

I have come across only [one example](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2018/10/10/Autograd-and-the-derivative-of-an-integral-function/) (a blog post containing an example) of automatic differentiation (AD) of an integral and I would like to see more, specially involving multiple integrals.

Comment: What's the problem with moving the derivative inside the integral? Are the assumptions of [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) not satisfied?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The problem, as I see it, is the complexity of $F(x,y, \xi, \eta)$. This makes the analytical derivative lengthier than $F(x,y, \xi, \eta)$, aka expression swell, which is one of the problems AD was designed to solve, in spite of the integral.

Comment: You mention rational function. Is there any chance to use [Feynman's parameter trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization) to obtain the integral before doing the derivative?